# Is it possible to check an OS X accessibility setting from a python script?

Tags: python, macos

Is it possible to detect an accessibility setting—specifically, `Display -> Shake Mouse Cursor to Locate` from a python script? I'd like to conditionally, rather than unilaterally, warn users to turn this off when using the script.

I'm operating with Mojave, if this functionality were available only to certain versions of OS X I should also wish to know that (or be pointed to where such information exists).

Comment: If nothing else, there should be a command-line utility that can retrieve this option. (I see there is a man page for something called `accesstool` that appears to be what you want, but the man page does nothing except describe it as the "CLI interface to the accessibility API". Worse, there's no indication of where the tool actually *is*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `defaults` from the CLI. Run this command:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences CGDisableCursorLocationMagnification
```

It returns `0` if shake mouse pointer to locate is enabled, and `1` if it is disabled.

Comment: Since it's implicit, anyone who doesn't understand why this is a correct answer (since it contains no python) should read the docs on python's [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), which will allow one to execute CLI commands from within a python script.